How to make a fair tournament with $8$ teams.
I am creating a tournament, I want $8$ teams all to play the same number of games. Although it would be acceptable to have some teams play $1$ extra game. I want there to be a max of around $4$ rounds because of how long it takes to setup and play the game.
I am looking for not only a winner, but for placements. It's okay if there are ties for a placement.
I created a bracket where everyone played three rounds, but I ended up with $4$ teams tied for fourth place and thought that would be discouraging for the team that gets eighth.
Because this is for a real tournament a lot of the numbers are flexible, but I'm interested if people have any good recommendations.
I also want to emphasize that I want this to feel fair, which to me means the order of who you play shouldn't effect your final placement.

I suggest Swiss-system, with for example Sonneborn-Berger score to manage ties. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie-breaking_in_Swiss-system_tournaments

If the only information obtained from a match is "Team $A$ beat Team $B$" - that is, there are no statistics such as score that you can use to make additional decisions, and if your assume "transitivity" (i.e., if $A$ beats $B$ and $B$ beats $C$, then it is assumed that $A$ will also beat $C$ without having to play the match), then what you are looking for is actually an efficient sorting algorithm.
